# Include Multiple Stylesheets in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress plugin, where I need to include multiple stylesheets and JS files.

I have used the following code,

**1. TRIAL 1- Including styles and scripts together**

```
define( 'DELTA__PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'imwi_scripts'); 
    function imwi_scripts() {

        wp_register_style( 'delta-styles', DELTA__PLUGIN_URL . "css/style.css" );
        wp_register_style( 'delta-styles', DELTA__PLUGIN_URL . "css/jquery.dataTables.css" );
        wp_register_style( 'delta-styles', DELTA__PLUGIN_URL . "css/font-awesome.min.css" );

        wp_register_script( 'delta-scripts', plugins_url('/js/jquery.dataTables.js', __FILE__) , array('jquery'), true );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'delta-styles' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'delta-scripts' );
    }
```

**2. TRIAL 2-Including scripts and styles seperately**

```
define( 'DELTA__PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );

//EN-QUEUING JAVASCRIPTS
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'imwi_scripts'); 
    function imwi_scripts() {

        wp_register_script( 'delta-scripts', plugins_url('/js/jquery.dataTables.js', __FILE__) , array('jquery'), true );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'delta-scripts' );
    }

//EN-QUEUING STYLES
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "imwi_styles");
    function imwi_styles() {
        wp_register_style( 'delta-styles', DELTA__PLUGIN_URL . "css/style.css" );
        wp_register_style( 'delta-styles', DELTA__PLUGIN_URL . "css/jquery.dataTables.css" );
        wp_register_style( 'delta-styles', DELTA__PLUGIN_URL . "css/font-awesome.min.css" );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'delta-styles' );
    }
```

**RESULT**
1. jquery.dataTables.js and style.css is getting enqueued in the page successfully.

**PROBLEM:**

1. jquery.dataTables.css and font-awesome.min.css didnot get included.
2. I want to keep my styles seperate, so I can't import my stylesheets into a single stylesheet (say delta.css) and en-queue the delta.css through wp_enqueue_style().
3. Use of CDN is not possible, because [WordPress.org Plugins] mailed back with this response *Offloading images, js, css, cgi, and other scripts to Google (or jquery.com or anywhere else frankly) is disallowed because you're introducing an unnecessary dependency on another site.*

**QUESTION:** Is it possible to include all the scripts and styles without creating multiple functions per stylesheet and script?

Thank you for helping..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. You need to have a different name for each script using `wp_register_style`

From the [codex on this topic](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) :

`<?php wp_register_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media ); ?>`

*$handle
(string) (required) Name of the stylesheet (which should be unique as it is used to identify the script in the whole system).
Default: None*

So, instead of calling all three (from example 1) `delta-styles` , call them

1. delta-styles
2. delta-styles-jquery
3. delta-styles-font-awesome

Then wp_enqueue_style all three so:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'delta-scripts' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'delta-scripts-jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'delta-scripts-font-awesome' );
```